# how to test an attribute's attribute of an object type prop in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

This is what my jsx file contains,
    `{'  '+this.props.file.attached.name}`
 How can I write test for this `name` ?

Comment: Do a select against the element that contains that as it's child and check it's inner text?

Comment: `expect(wrapper.find('.attachedFile').text()).to.equal(' apple');` is this what you meant? I got  an assertion error undefined to equal apple

Comment: Hmm, not sure if the `text` prop works for a specific node.  Try this type of approach: `expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<div> apple</div>)).to.equal(true)`

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement([<div class="attachedFile"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>  apple</div>])).to.equal(true);
```

This works perfect,ensure that you surround the elements with []